# How to include an external library in a React native project in Android Studio?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, react-native

I'm porting a web app over to a React app in Android Studio. I'm using an external library (this one: https://trackingjs.com/). And as I'm fairly new to Android Studio and React, I'm sure how to do it correctly. In my webapp I'm just including it with a script tag.

I have the library saved into my project folder, in the same directory as my index.android.js file. I would prefer not to alter the code in tracking.js in any way. I'm not sure how to proceed. This must be a common problem but I've had little luck finding anything that works.

Comment: Tracking.js does have an node package ("tracking").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @liminal18's comments, this is what worked for me, using Tracking.js:

```
$ npm install tracking
```

on the command line, then in index.android.js

```
import {
Tracking
} from 'tracking';
```

This was just to get the library included without errors. Since Tracking.js is web-based, there might be issues actually using it, but doing the above solved the problem of including an external library.

Comment: might want to include --save so npm knows which section to add it to. Did it work? I might consider using it if it did.

Comment: Yeah this worked. I still have to modify the library so that it works better with React-native since Tracking is so element-based. But that's one less hurdle.

Comment: I am really impressed you got that far. I just gave up on porting xml parsers for rss feeds and decided to use a service, if you do port it let me know and be sure to publish the package.

Answer (score 2):

If it is available from npm you can do npm install packageName --save and then use import Package from 'packages.js'

Please do keep in mind react native is not quite javascript and some browser specific functions will not transpile in other words it is possible the plugin you are using will not work in react native.

Btw no need for android studio except for starting the emulated device to run react native in. You should be able to react-native run-android and provided you set up the emulated device correctly it will start the package manager and install your app on it and then refresh on save. Are you using the react native cli?

Btw in your web app you should be able to include it using let tracking = require("tracking.js") or using the import style above. If you do it should be concatenated into your main.js file and then minified which might help. Better to have one download than several.

Comment: I'm using both the react native cli and Android Studio. I have problems using Android Studio by itself (although I guess I'm using it as a glorified text editor). I think I've done something horribly wrong in my project setup as every time I open AS and edit my js file it says it's not part of the project. Every time I want to test the code I have to resync the code with the gradle files, which does not seem right either. And forget iOS. I can't get anything to work in Xcode at all. Basically I'm just suffering from a heavy case of n00bitis. Luckily this is just a side project.

Comment: React Native is hard. I get red screens all the time sometimes just from installing new npm libs while running. Takes some time. Stick to the tutorials etc. anyways it has to be included with either require or import in react native so see if you can manage that via an npm install and then require.

Comment: Where in the folder structure should the node module be installed? I tried the top level (in that theoretically, both ios and android could see it), but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Also, where would I find (or create) packages.js?

Comment: Oh wait, packages.js refers to the specific package?

Comment: Yeah try installing a known react native package from pm and including the react native material package is nice. Then import or require it either one works. That should at least tell you how to import a package.

Comment: I wasn't getting anywhere with npm, so I tried running 'react-native link', and this screwed up my gradle file. I had previously installed react-native-webrtc, and I guess I must have tried using npm with that before using another method (this was a few months ago. I only remember doing something with it in Android Studio). @liminal18 Do you know the specific commands to install something with npm?

Comment: Npm install packageName -save or yarn add packageName if you use yarn.

Comment: Btw react-native link is for linkined libraries written in java, objective-c, or swift to a react native project. For a javascript npm package just installing it and then rewuiring it inside your react native javascript fiels should suffice

Comment: thanks for your help. I've installed the package via npm, and added the import, but cannot access anything (and now the gradle thing is a separate problem. My code is completely borked :-( ) Ah well. If you get a chance, please clarify your answer above with specific instructions (and use code formatting for code or commands, which makes it easier to read).